# How to add Show more functionality for the list tag which is getting values from database?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the values of the li tag from the database and displaying the same. When I am trying to add show more function, I am get it in loop, two times "show more". but i have entered once. 
I am having my ul tag and li tag inside script tag. also I have nested div inside my li tag.

The code is as follows as.

```
<script type="text/mustache" id="resource-list-template">
            <ul class="resources">
                {{#resources}}
                    <li data-id="{{id}}" class="resource">
                        <div class="tags">
                            {{#comment}}
                                <span title="Comment available" class="tag resource-comment-available">!</span>
                            {{/comment}}
                            {{#averageRating}}
                                <span class="average-rating rating" title="{{averageRating}} out of 5 stars ({{ratingCount}} reviews)"><span class="rating-bar" style="width: {{averageRatingPercent}}%">{{averageRating}}/5 stars</span></span>
                            {{/averageRating}}
                            {{#files}}
                                <a href="{{url}}" href="_blank" class="language-flag language-flag-{{language.code}} file-link" data-id="{{id}}"
                                    title="{{language.name}}" target="_blank">
                                    {{language.name}}
                                </a>
                            {{/files}}
                            <button class="toggle-resource-details-button" 
                                title="Show or hide reviews and details for this resource">+</button>
                        </div>
                        {{#prefix}}
                            <span class="resource-prefix">{{prefix}}</span>
                        {{/prefix}}
                        <a href="{{primaryURL}}" target="_blank" title="{{title}}">
                            {{title}}
                        </a>

                        <div class="resource-details">



                            <div class="resource-review-page resource-details-page">
                                {{^hasReviewed}}
                                    <div>
                                        <dt>Your Rating:</dt>
                                        <dd><span class="rating editable"><span class="rating-bar"></span></span></dd>
                                    </div>
                                    <dl>
                                        <dt>Your Name:</dt>
                                        <dd><input type="text" class="review-author" placeholder=" Please Enter your Name(Mandatory)"></dd>
                                    </dl>
                                    <div>
                                        <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here (Mandatory)"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="submit-review-button" disabled>Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                {{/hasReviewed}}
                                {{#hasReviewed}}
                                    <p>You already have reviewed this resource.</p>
                                {{/hasReviewed}}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                {{/resources}}
            </ul>
        <p> I Tried added Read more here </p>
        </script>
```

Can any one help me in sorting this out. I am unable to move further. I tried many variants. But nothing goes good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have HTML inside of a `<script>` tag.

Comment: But the code seems to works correctly.

Comment: @georgiaboy82: That is a `moustache` template. Please check the `type` next time :) And yes, you can put HTML in a Script tag so long as the type is not `text/javascript`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie sorry about that, thought he was just messing around by putting moustache.

Comment: @georgiaboy82: Like: "I know... I'll just make my script wear a moustache and nobody will recognise it" :)

Comment: I tried adding the following script and it does have no impact. I am getting the span value two times and no function being called. resources: function() {
    $( 'span' ).click( function() {
        $( '.resources li:hidden' ).slice( 0, 2 ).show();
        if( $( '.resources li' ).length == $( '.resources li:visible' ).length ) {
$( 'span ' ).hide();                
  }
    } );
}